# A suitable database structure to use with this kind of project?

Tags: php, database, data-structures

I'm working on a site analysis project. Where users will be able to record/view their site traffic reports by using my API (like Google Analytics).

The problem is, I'm not sure how I should setup the database structure.

I already have some tables setup for user management purposes:

User table: `|| userID || userName || datReg ||`

Account information table: `|| accountInfoID || userID || fName || lName || emailAddress ||`

So I was thinking I could do something like:

Site analysis table: `|| analyID || userID || visitorIP || visitorCountry || pageviewCount || pageviewData`

But would that be scalable? I mean, with that structure there could be tens of thousands of rows inserted every **day**, so would that not result to being very slow after a few months?

With the idea above, I would run a query similar to this, for each unique visit:

```
INSERT INTO siteAnaly (userID,visitorIP,visitorCountry,pageviewCount,pageviewData) VALUES ("the accounts holders user ID","the visitors IP","the visitors country","the visitors apge view count","a JSON array of the visitors pageview URI's")
```

and then, on every pageview, that row inserted fro the query above, would be updated. Incrementing the `pageviewCount` and appending to `pageviewData`

The other idea I had (which you may think is stupid) was to have a new table for every user, named with the users ID.

What do you think is the best approach to take with a project like this?

Comment: Can you share some of the queries you'd want to run using this data? That usually helps in defining the best structure...

Comment: Updated the post @NevilleK xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will indeed have lots of data input, what you will need to do in this case is to split data in different tables and even databases at one point to make sure you don't clutter your main datasource. Rarely will you need to query large portions of data that will not have been processed so your goal is to:

1. Create a database that stores your unprocessed data for later reference
2. Create a processed database that compiles all the possible data in aggregated tables
3. Create a script that will generate the agregated data
4. Create an application that can lookup data from today's unprocessed data if you absolutely need it live.

A good conference i went to see and did a review on it was posted on my blog, you might want to read it:

http://crazycoders.net/2012/03/confoo-2012-continous-data-processing/

Good luck

Comment: hmmm. That seems like allot of work. What do you think about the "create a new table for each user" idea?

Comment: Could also be a good approach. The thing is to keep in mind that if you want to scale, make sure your data is as loose as possible so it can be splitted into multiple tables if need be. And please, use pre-processing for your reports, you will kill your server if you have thousands of users trying to generate live reports and don't have the infrastructure for it...

Comment: Right! What do you mean by `processed` and `unprocessed` data? Thanks

Comment: For example, instead of always COUNT()'ing and SUM()'ing your data to make subtotals or calculate day to day values, pre-process that data into intermediate tables such as user_dailyvisits table that will already contains the total visits for today, this way, you won't count the data over and over again but select the already counted data... NOTE: Do not delete your original data, if in 1 month you add a new report, you want to be able to pre-compile the old data too, not just the new one...

Comment: This is why having two databases, one for the raw unprocessed data and one for the processed pre-compiled report data is better, you can always split the data in two machines later and scale easily.

Comment: ah, right! That make sense. So maybe a table for each user with the unprocessed data and a separate table that stores all basic report data for each user (todaysVists, yesterdaysVists, monthsVisits) including the `userID` to represent which user belongs to what record. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

`visitorIP` and `vistorCountry` can be moved to different table. These values will surely repeat. What kind of data you want to keep in `pageViewData`?

Comment: `pageViewData` would contain a `JSON` array of each page URI visited. Also, moving the `visitorIP` and `visitorCountry` to another table would not make any difference. The structure will still result to 1 table with a **huge** amount of records which == slow performance, right?

Comment: If you have multiple visits from the same ip address then moving these fields to another table should help. Remember that not everyone have unique ip. You can also decrease significance of performance problem with huge data sets by using non-relational database, like mongodb.